# Using multiple FluentValidators on MediatR pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation, mediatr

I have a MediatR pipeline behavior like this:

```
public class FailFastRequestBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IValidator> _validators;

    public FailFastRequestBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        var failures = _validators
            .Select(async v => await v.ValidateAsync(request))
            .SelectMany(result => result.Result.Errors)
            .Where(f => f != null);


        return failures.Any()
            ? Errors(failures)
            : next();
    }

    ...
}
```

And MediatR commands like this:

```
public class MyUseCase
{
    public class Command : IRequest<CommandResponse>
    {
        ...
    }

    public class Validator : AbstractValidator<Command>
    {
        ...
    }

    public class Handler<T>: IRequestHandler<T, CommandResponse>
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The validators are registered on `Startup.cs` like this:

```
        AssemblyScanner
          .FindValidatorsInAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MyUseCase)))
            .ForEach(result => 
                services.AddScoped(result.InterfaceType, result.ValidatorType));
```

This works nice for the `MyUseCase.Validator`, it is injected on the pipeline and is executed, validating the `MyUseCase.Command`.

But it's a large application, and many commands have common properties, i.e. every order operation receives an `OrderId` and I have to check if the Id is valid, if the entity exists in database, if the authenticated user is the owner of the order being modified, etc.

So I tried to create the following interface and validator:

```
public interface IOrder
{
    string OrderId { get; set; }
}

public class IOrderValidator : AbstractValidator<IOrder>
{
    public IOrderValidator()
    {
        CascadeMode = CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure;

        RuleFor(x => x.OrderId)
            .Rule1()
            .Rule2()
            .Rule3()
            .RuleN()
    } 
}
```

Finally I changed the command to this:

```
public class MyUseCase
{
    public class Command : IRequest<CommandResponse>: IOrder
    {
        ...
    }

    public class Validator : AbstractValidator<Command>
    {
        ...
    }

    public class Handler<T>: IRequestHandler<T, CommandResponse>
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `IOrderValidator` is not injected in the pipeline, only the `MyUseCase.Validator` is.

Am I missing something here or is it even possible to inject multiple validators in the pipeline?

Comment: all you need to do is register `IOrderValidator`  as an `IValidator<IOrder>` basically change the code of the assembly scanner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Service resolution depends on the DI container that you use. It seems that you use built-in .NET Core container and it cannot resolve contravariant interfaces.

Consider [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org) instead as it knows how to work with contravariance. This sample code will resolve all the validators you need:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();

    container.Collection.Append<IValidator<IOrder>, OrderValidator>();
    container.Collection.Append<IValidator<Command>, CommandValidator>();

    var validators = container.GetAllInstances<IValidator<Command>>();

    validators.Should().HaveCount(2);
}
```

Alternatively you have to explicitly register your validators parameterized with all commands they must apply to:

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    var provider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddTransient(typeof(IValidator<Command>), typeof(OrderValidator))
        .AddTransient(typeof(IValidator<Command>), typeof(CommandValidator))
        .BuildServiceProvider();

    var validators = provider.GetServices<IValidator<Command>>();

    validators.Should().HaveCount(2);
}
```

Note the difference between `IOrder` and `Command` for `OrderValidator` registration in case of Simple Injector and .NET Core DI container:

```
container.Collection.Append<IValidator<IOrder>, OrderValidator>();
servcies.AddTransient(typeof(IValidator<Command>), typeof(OrderValidator))
```

Assuming following classes and interfaces are defined:

```
interface IOrder
{
}

class Command : IRequest<CommandResponse>, IOrder
{
}

class CommandResponse
{
}

class OrderValidator : AbstractValidator<IOrder>
{
}

class CommandValidator : AbstractValidator<Command>
{
}
```

Comment: .Net-Core DI has the same support

Comment: all you need to do is register IOrderValidator as an IValidator<IOrder>

Comment: @johnny5, nope, you can try yourself. Install required MediatR, FluentValidation and FluentAssertion packages and run the test.

Comment: Oh I see now, `Command` inherits from `IOrder` you're saying the list of Validators isn't populated properly because `CommandValidator` is an `IValidator<Command>` instead of `IValidator<IOrder>`

Comment: @johnny5, yeah, and the MediatR resolves validator based on concrete command type, not the interface. So in .NET Core container both validators have to be registered as `IValidator<Command>`. And same has to be done for all commands that have to be validated by `OrderValidator`.